# AWS Lambda: use the same layer for multiple Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a layer by providing `.zip` of couple of python dependencies.

I want to use this layer for multiple Lambdas.

But after adding the above to one Lambdas, it will not be available for any other Lambdas.

Do I have to create another layer with same zip folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But after adding the above to one Lambdas, it will not be available for any other Lambdas.

This is incorrect. The same layer may be associated with multiple lambdas at the same time. From [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aws-lambda-now-supports-custom-runtimes-and-layers/):

> Lambda Layers are a new type of artifact that can contain arbitrary code and data, and may be referenced by zero, one, or more functions at the same time.

---

P.S. There are, in fact, public layers which you might find helpful depending on your needs:

- https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers
- https://github.com/mthenw/awesome-layers

Comment: thanks, its true that we can add same layer for multiple lambdas.  i added the solution work around to get this done.